# A Double Integral Problem

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^{\ln5} \int_{e^x}^6 \frac1{\ln y} \,dy\,dx$$
How to do this? I changed the order of integration at first and I graphed the initial problem. I thought $dy$ was integrated from $0$ to $6$  and $x$ was from $0$ to $\ln5$ but it failed.

Answer (score 0):

The integration range is $$\{(x,\,y)|x\in [0,\,\ln 5],\,y\in [e^x,\,6]\}=\{(x,\,y)|y\in[1,\,6],\,x\in[0,\,\ln\min\{ y,\,5\}\},$$so the integral is $$\int_1^6\left(\int_0^{\ln\min\{ y,\,5\}}dx\right)\frac{dy}{\ln y}=\int_1^5dy+\ln 5\int_5^6\frac{dy}{\ln y}=4+(\operatorname{li}(6)-\operatorname{li}(5))\ln 5.$$